# Java vs Elasticsearch. Where to put logic?

Tags: java, elasticsearch, search, business-logic

Common example, I have many items in elasticsearch. Every item has:

```
id
name
price
storeConnectionId
regionConnectionId
```

There can be items with different ids but the same name and I want to add some logic of aggregation to the search.

- If item exists at your region, I want to return exactly this item with id and price for this region.
- If there’s no such item in your region, I want to return only the cheapest item

I see few solutions here:

1. Put whole logic to elasticsearch. Create awesome aggregations and bool queries. And keep only one request to elasticsearch.
2. Use two queries. First will return items for requested region and second one will return all items with min price aggregation.
3. Return every item from the search regardless, and keep this business logic at Java.

Elasticsearch only supposed to be working faster with big amount of items, but is that ok to much such logic to elasticsearch query?

Comment: I'd say that the logic for a related feature should be kept at the same place as much as you can. So if you want to do it all in Java, do it. But if ES can help you leverage the burden for a feature and the performance doesn't suffer, why would you refrain from leveraging ES?

Comment: Question seems more on topic at https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I don't really see how you put the "whole logic to elasticsearch" when it is still your Java code making the query (and deciding what goes in). So this is still "all in one place" in my book. It would be a different matter if you had to put additional logic into the index generation as well to support this kind of query, that would add a "complexity burden". But just making full use of the existing query capabilities against fields that are organically present should be "simple enough".

Comment: #1 or #2 ok, but #3 sounds fairly pointless. ES is a database with a query api after all, plus the business logic (partially encoded as an ES query) stays on the java side in #2 as well.